# reboot/halt/suspend suddenly stopped working

Tags: reboot

I have ubuntu 20.10, installed on ThinkPad X1 Extreme (Intel i7).
A few days ago, reboot/halt/suspend stopped working (**sudo halt** just returns and nothing happens. Same for **sudo reboot**).

I really have no idea what went wrong or how to fix it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades